# Is there any matrix $2\times 2$ such that $A\neq I$ but $ A^3=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Is there any $2 \times 2$ matrix $A \neq I$ such that $A^3=I$?

In my opinion: no. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think it is a matter of opinions...

Comment: See also: [How to construct a $2\times 2$ real matrix $A$ not equal to Identity such that $A^3=I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182632)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rotation by $2\pi/3$ in the plane.  Find the $2 \times 2$ matrix that gives you this linear transformation.

Comment: Hi! How did you get that?

Comment: Imagine something when applied 3 times is the identity.  How do you think?

Comment: Ok, I'll think. thanks

Answer (score 13):

Since you don't specify what field the entries of this matrix have to come from, I could just take a diagonal matrix whose entries are $1$ and $\omega$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i /3}$ is a primitive cube root of 1 in the complex numbers.

I guess you want real or integer entries though.  If $A^3=I$ then the eigenvalues of $A$, that is, the roots of the characteristic polynomial, have to be third roots of unity.  A primitive third root of unity satisfies $x^2+x+1=0$, so you could look for a matrix over the integers with that as a characteristic polynomial....

Comment: +1. Nice! Your argument shows that this holds for *any* (nonzero) commutative ring.

Comment: Another way to get an integral matrix that does the job it to take the automorphism of order $3$ of the torus, then the induced map on homology.  In fact, there's an automorphism of order $6$ coming from the symmetry of the hexagonal tiling.

Comment: @Ryan: over $\mathbb Z$, you have reduced to the problem to the (equivalent, I'm pretty sure---given enough technology) one of finding an automorphism of order $3$ of the torus :)

Comment: Yes, $2\times 2$ matrices of the integers of finite order all come from symmetries of the torus.  This is a special case of what's called the Nielsen Realization problem -- which is solved, by-the-way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen_realization_problem Among other things, this gives you a fairly intuitive way to enumerate all the finite-order elements of $GL_2 \mathbb Z$ (up to conjugacy).