# How to construct a $2\times 2$ real matrix $A$ not equal to Identity such that $A^3=I$?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

How to construct a $2\times 2$ real matrix $A$ not equal to Identity such
that $A^3=I$?

There is a correspondence between the ring of complex numbers and the
ring  of  $2\times2$ matrices (0 matrix
is included!) i.e.,$$a+ib\leftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$

Can I apply this result and construct such matrix?

Comment: rotation by $2\pi/3$

Comment: are you saying $\cos(2\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)$ I must map to the corresponding matrix?

Comment: @butt: I guess this should be an answer rather than a comment...

Comment: Every non-identity 2x2 real matrix satisfying $A^3=I$ is conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, via the rational canonical form.

Comment: See also: [Is there any matrix $2\times 2$ such that $A\neq I$ but $ A^3=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58666).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the three cube roots of $1$.  Let $a+bi$ be one of those.  They are solutions of $x^3=1$.  Hence $x^3-1=0$.

Since $1$ is one of the solutions, $x-1$ must be one of the factors, thus:
$$
x^3-1 = (x-1)(\cdots\cdots\cdots).
$$
Fill in the blanks by doing long division.  You should get
$$
(x-1)(x^2+x+1).
$$
So the equation is
$$
(x-1)(x^2+x+1) = 0.
$$
That implies
$$
x-1=0\quad\text{or}\quad x^2+x+1 = 0.
$$
Solve the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there are also $2\times2$ matrices which are not of the form indicated in the question which solve the problem that $A^3=I$. The general solution to your problem is ($\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \beta\neq 0$)
$$A =\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta\\
-\beta^{-1}(1+\alpha+\alpha^2) & -(1+\alpha)\end{pmatrix} .$$

The specific examples which correspond to complex numbers $a+ib$ need to fulfill
$$\alpha = -(1+\alpha) \quad \text{and} \quad\beta = \beta^{-1}(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)$$
with the solutions $\alpha=-1/2$, $\beta=\pm\sqrt{3}/2$ (corresponding to rotation by $\pm 2\pi/3$).

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-c&-b\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $A^2+bA+cI=0$.

So the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $A^3-I=(A-I)(A^2+A+I)=0$